# I am unable to download eglibc 2.14 source through svn as www.eglibc.org seems to be down since the last 2 days. Is there an alternate way?

Tags: svn, glibc, cross-compilation

I am trying to build a cross-compiler using crosstool-ng 1.12.2. It bails out while trying to download the eglibc 2.14 packages. Here is the log:

```
DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'svn' 'export' '-r' 'HEAD' 'http://www.eglibc.org/svn/branches/eglibc-2_14/libc' 'eglibc-2_14'

[WARN ]    Could not retrieve 'eglibc-2_14'

[ERROR]

[ERROR]    >>  Build failed in step 'Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs'

[ERROR]    >>

[ERROR]    >>  Error happened in: do_libc_get[scripts/build/libc/eglibc.sh]

[ERROR]    >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@530]
```

Here is the result from ping:

```
PING eglibc.org (67.207.128.95) 56(84) bytes of data.


--- eglibc.org ping statistics ---

41 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 40000ms
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_GLIBC), features of eglibc have been merged back into glibc, and development on eglibc has halted.

Aurélien Jarno has also [noted](http://blog.aurel32.net/175) back in June about Debian switching back to glibc, and the features missing in glibc that have yet to be merged/committed.

As a side note, why are you still using crosstool-ng 1.12.0?

Comment: Also, if you are having problems accessing crosstool-ng.org, there is a mirror of the git repository [here](https://github.com/yann-morin-1998/crosstool-ng).